# How to call other library method from Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-jsom

I'm building a Reactjs component for SharePoint 2013 page. In the SharePoint JSOM, I can get the current context by calling GetCurrentCtx(). I want to call this method in my ReactJs component but I don't how to do:

```
import React from 'react';

class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {likesCount:0, listTitle:''};
        this.onLike = this.onLink.bind(this);
    }

    onLink(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var ctx = GetCurrentCtx(); //<- this line doesn't work.
        this.setState({listTitle:ctx.ListTitle});
        return false;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div>List Title: {this.state.listTitle}</div>
                <div><button onClick={this.onClick}>Get List Title</button></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TestComponent;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
import { GetCurrentCtx } from './filepath_for_this_function_export'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `import` file/component where is your `method`

Comment: the problem i'm facing is I don't have the source file of the function GetCurrentCtx(). This function is loaded by the SharePoint page. I can just call this method in embed snipplet. I guess the method is located in SP.js or Core.js . If I import this file in the component, will it bundled in final file?